# Spring Boot Resources From Executable WAR, WAR, and STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I run my project from STS or when I drop the WAR in an existing Tomcat, the project works runs as expected. When I run the WAR file as an executable, I get `FileNotFoundException` errors.

I have a directory `/resources/private/` that contains static content and data that I want to access privately and not made available with images, css, js, etc...

How can I access the `/resources/` directory regardless of how I deploy the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ApplicationContext :

```
@Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    Resource[] resources = context.getResources("classpath:*.json");
```

Source: https://github.com/RedFroggy/angular-spring-dynamic-form/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/redfroggy/dynamicforms/configuration/ExtraFieldConfiguration.java

Comment: Michael D., I appreciate the answer, unfortunately I was not successful with implementing it. I looked at the example in the link as well and tried to duplicate but was not able to get it working.

I didn't realize how difficult it was to do something that seems to be so simple. I understand that the jar/war file is not expanded when you try to execute it, but there has to be a universal way to get access to the files in the `classpath`. I wanted to give my application the ability to run as a standalone executable war at the same as something you can drop in an existing container.